# What are the difference between scope "IMAP.AccessAsUser.All" and "https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All" of MSAL?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get access token to get access to Outlook by IMAP using MSAL.

The code used to get the access token is below(written by Kotlin).

```
    fun getAccessTokenByMSAL(
        appId: String,
        scopes: List<String>
    ): String? {
        val scopeSet = HashSet<String>()
        scopes.stream().forEach { scope ->
            scopeSet.add(scope)
        }
        val app = PublicClientApplication
            .builder(appId)
            .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common")
            .build();
        val params = InteractiveRequestParameters
            .builder(URI("http://localhost:8080"))
            .scopes(scopeSet)
            .build()
        val result = app.acquireToken(params).join()
        return result.accessToken()
    }
```

To get access to Outlook by IMAP, I want to add "IMAP.AccessAsUser.All" permission as scope like below.

```
        val scopes = listOf(
            "https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All",
        )
        val token = getAccessTokenByMSAL(appId, scopes)
```

However, as a result, when I try to log in with my personal account, I get the following error message in my browser (The error message has no embedded character string and is displayed strangely.):

```
Authentication failed. You can return to the application. Feel free to close this browser tab.

Error details: error {0} error_description: {1}
```

When I change scope as follows and try again, then authentication success.

```
        val scopes = listOf(
            "IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"
        )

        val token = getAccessTokenByMSAL(appId, scopes)
```

So, what are the difference between scope "IMAP.AccessAsUser.All" and "https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"?

And which is correct to get right access token to connect Outlook by IMAP?

Answer (score 0):

It's a mess.

```
IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
```

E.g.,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
```

Is a Microsoft Graph audience scope, but it seems its completely useless client-side, and is only used when adding scopes to your app.

On the other hand,

```
https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
```

Is the scope you have to request client-side, if you want to access Exchange mailboxes using IMAP with OAuth 2.0.

You can't add it to your application scopes, but if you add:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
```

It allows you to request *both* of the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
```

I'm talking from my experience trying to access Exchange Enterprise (in-tenant) mailboxes via IMAP with OAuth 2.0. It could be different for personal and school accounts.